# BadRequestException in AWS CLI when trying to import a swagger.json file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, swagger-2.0

I'm working on AWS API Gateway and trying to import a Swagger JSON file using AWS CLI. Following is the command I used to import.

```
aws apigateway import-rest-api --parameters endpointConfigurationTypes=REGIONAL  --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --body D:/aws/test.json --no-fail-on-warnings
```

But I'm getting this error:

> An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the ImportRestApi operation: Invalid OpenAPI input.

The test.json is looked fine, I tried it in the AWS console and it was working.
I don't understand why it is not working when I try to use AWS CLI. I'm using AWS CLI version 2. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `file://` as explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-file.html):

```
--body file://C:\aws\test.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried that and it is not working

Comment: @user " it is not working " - is not specific. Exactly what is happening? Any error messages?

Comment: I'm getting a different error now, "Unknown output type: None"

Comment: @user This probably means new issue. You should make new question and provide the full `test.json`.

Comment: ok thanks, will create a new issue